# TimeSpan.ParseExact returns System.FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have the following code:

```
var point = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, "hh\\:mm\\:ss\\,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and my input format is:

```
00:00:15,680
```

It's quite easy task I know.
But I always get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.'
```

So what I do wrong ? Can you help me with my specific task ?
Actually I've already tried so many formats but unfortunately noone is correct.

Comment: That works for me, parsing your input string `00:00:15,680` prints `00:00:15.6800000` Are you sure your input is exactly that?

Comment: Can you show us how you're assigning your input?

Comment: @Douglas yes you're right. I got the error because my input contains value with tiny space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) definition, the syntax is:

`input format`, etc

The `System.FormatException` exception message is about the `input` parameter, the first parameter from the list that is in the function's prototype. I would double check the value of the `input` parameter from your code.